# how can you detect if a android device has software keys? (hasPermanentMenuKey is not a solution)

Tags: android

I need to know if the device on which my app is running has a navigation bar or not.

hasPermanentMenuKey is not a solution because there are some devices (ex. Samsung S5) which haven't the navigation bar but haven't the menu key too.

Is there any way method to get this info? probably even a way to get the value of qemu.hw.mainkeys in build.prop would be a solution...

Thank you!

Comment: "I need to know if the device on which my app is running has a navigation bar or not" -- what problem are you trying to solve where you need this information?

Comment: There are a lot of cases where this info is useful. For example, sometimes when you are using translucent system bars, you cannot use setFitsSystemWindows() to set the padding of the current window (this happens for example when you are working with dialogs or with a preferenceActivity).
It's not only a problem regarding layout, you may want to assign some different behavior to devices that have software keys...

Comment: "you cannot use setFitsSystemWindows() to set the padding of the current window" -- AFAIK, there is no guaranteed size for the navigation bar. Hence, I still don't see how knowing whether or not the navigation bar exists helps you. All that does is tell you that the size is 0 or greater than 0. "you may want to assign some different behavior to devices that have software keys" -- you're welcome to do that, but I wouldn't advise it. Also, bear in mind that `qemu.hw.mainkeys`, based on its name, would appear to be tied to the emulator, though there may be an equivalent for production hardware.

Comment: 1 - It's not a definitive solution but to set the bottom padding to 50dp will fit the 90% of devices. Better that nothing...
2 - Yes, you're right :-/ 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
public static boolean hasNavBar(Context context)
    {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        int resourceId = res.getIdentifier(SHOW_NAV_BAR_RES_NAME, "bool", "android");

        if (resourceId != 0)
        {
            String sNavBarOverride = "";
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            {
                try
                {
                    Class c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
                    Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("get", String.class);
                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    sNavBarOverride = (String) m.invoke(null, "qemu.hw.mainkeys");
                }
                catch (Throwable e)
                {
                    sNavBarOverride = "";
                }
            }
            boolean hasNav = res.getBoolean(resourceId);
            // check override flag (see static block)
            if ("1".equals(sNavBarOverride))            
                hasNav = false;         
            else if ("0".equals(sNavBarOverride))
                hasNav = true;
            return hasNav;
        }
        else
        { // fallback
            return !ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
        }
    }
```